# bending rigidity of a metal rod

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials

Say you have a metal rod with a square cross section (say 10cm by 10cm) of a certain length. You'd like to make it less prone to bending. Is it better to:

1. keep it the way it is

or

2. remove material so that it has a T shaped cross section

I wonder if removing material would actually make it more rigid from a bending perspective simply due to the T shaped cross section.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the thing bending from its own weight, or from applied forces?

Comment: applied forces, but I believe the answer below on 2nd moment of inertia already answered it. thanks

Comment: Actually, if you're talking about a cantilevered beam, the reduction in weight of a "T" section may outweigh (as it were) the reduction in strength.  I'd have to do the math, and there'd be all sorts of interesting issues with stability against buckling vs. the length of the beam.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is look at the I value (I want to call it moment of inertia but this terms varies slightly depending where you are in the world) for the section.   If you are limiting the T section to the same maximum values as the square section, the T section is going to have a smaller I value.  Since your moment (bending) capacity is highly dependent on the I value, T section will correspondingly have a lower capacity compared to the square.

One of the advantages of using a T section is you may be able to reduce your material used.  If the T section has sufficient strength to meet your needs, then you would save the cost of the difference in the cross sectional areas.  Cost in terms of material in dollars as well as the cost of material in weight as well.

One of the nice things about the square shape is that it has the same bending capacity about X-X and Y-Y in both directions.  The T shape will have the same bending capacity about Y-Y in both directions, but its capacity will change about X-X depending which way its being bent.

One of the things that will limit your T section compared to your Square section is something called Lateral Torsional buckling.  Basically as the unsupported length of the beam increases, the section will want to start to twist.  As some point this twisting action (Torsion) will cause the member to buckle sideways and the beam to fail.

So of the two sections the square is stronger than the T.